# What is the difference between .js, .tsx and .jsx in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have come across these 3 main file types:

- `.js`
- `.tsx`
- `.jsx`

What is the difference between the 3? Which one should be used? Which one is used more commonly?

Comment: Have you done any research so far? The one that should be used depends largely on what's in the file.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

- `.js` is JavaScript, plain and simple

```
const Foo = () => {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello World!");
};
```

- `.ts` is [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), Microsoft's way of adding "concrete" types to JavaScript

```
const Foo: FunctionalComponent = () => {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello World!");
};
```

- `.jsx` is JavaScript but with [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) enabled which is React's language extension to allow you to write markup directly in code which is then compiled to plain JavaScript with the JSX replaced with direct API calls to `React.createElement` or whatever API is targeted

```
const Foo = () => {
    return <div>Hello World!</div>;
};
```

- `.tsx` is similar to **jsx** except it's TypeScript with the JSX language extension.

```
const Foo: FunctionalComponent = () => {
    return <div>Hello World!</div>;
};
```

All of these will compile down to JavaScript code.  See also [React Without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

---

Bear in mind that just because it has a certain extension, doesn't mean that that is what the file actually is (frustratingly).  I have run into several projects that use `.js` as an extension for files that include JSX syntax as well as a few that even include TypeScript.

Comment: I see! This makes sense. However, one follow-up question: when I bootstrap with `create-react-app`, the files have a `.js` extension, however, they look like the `.jsx` example you gave. Why is this?

Comment: Like I said, some use the js extension even though their files include JSX syntax. Its very frustrating. Some tools handle it gracefully and others throw errors because they expect only JavaScript in js files.

Comment: Ahh I see. Would you personally recommend JSX or TSX? Thanks!!

Comment: That's up to you. I like TypeScript, but sometimes it feels like it ends up slowing you down on very small projects.

Comment: I see, one more question: why can you write JSX code in a `.js` file? Doesn't that make `.jsx` files redundant?

Comment: It is not redundant. jsx should always be in a .jsx file, however, some programs are forgiving and will work even if it is mislabeled. But not all programs. jsx is not meant to be in a js file even if it does work.

Comment: Honestly, this is extremely frustrating for a beginner like me. My workplace uses `.jsx` with a Php backend but the course I am taking on Scrimba to learn React is using `.js` even for writing `JSX`.

Answer (score 10):

A **JS** file is a JavaScript file extension, this is used for any modules and snippets of code made in pure JavaScript. You should use JS files when writing functions that won't use any React feature but will be used among different React components.

**JSX** is a file syntax extension used by React, you can render component, import CSS files and use React hooks among other things. You should use JSX files when rendering a React component.

**TSX** is the TypeScript version of JSX, TypeScript is a superset that adds static typing in JavaScript. You should use TypeScript whenever it's possible to do so as it has numerous advantages (code scalability and static typing)

Comment: One question: when I bootstrap with `create-react-app` it creates a bunch of `.js` files, but they aren't plain JavaScript. Why is this?

Comment: What is used more commonly? JS, JSX, or TSX?

Comment: @NickSmith React is smart enough to understand React components inside a JS file even though it's not valid JavaScript. You can use both JS and JSX extension to use a React component. As far as what is used more commonly, it's a matter of choice. For bigger projects I'd like to use TypeScript, for medium projects I'd like to use Flow for static typing as an alternative to TS and lastly, for smaller projects, I use Plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

A **JS** file is a JavaScript file extension and This would be the fully Javascript functions only.

**JSX** is a file syntax extension used by React and here you can use CSS and Html as well. You should use JSX files when rendering a React component.

**TSX** is the TypeScript version of JSX

Answer (score 0):

In React, JavaScript (JS) is the primary language for writing code. However, React code is often written using JSX and TypeScript (TSX) for type safety. Here's the difference between these file extensions:

1. **.js (JavaScript):**

   - JavaScript is the fundamental programming language used for building React applications.
   - React components can be written in plain JavaScript using the .js extension.
   - In .js files, you can write React components using ES6 class components or functional components with the `function` keyword.
   - JSX (JavaScript XML) can also be used within .js files to describe the structure of the UI.

Example of a React component in a .js file:

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  return <div>Hello, World!</div>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

2. **.jsx (JavaScript + JSX):**

   - .jsx files are essentially the same as .js files but are explicitly named with the .jsx extension to indicate the usage of JSX syntax for defining React components.
   - JSX allows you to write HTML-like code within your JavaScript components, making it easier to define the structure of your UI elements.

Example of a React component in a .jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  return <div>Hello, World!</div>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

3. **.tsx (TypeScript + JSX):**

   - .tsx files are used when you want to incorporate TypeScript, a statically typed superset of JavaScript, into your React project.
   - TypeScript adds type checking to your code, making it more robust and less prone to certain types of errors.
   - Like .jsx files, .tsx files also use JSX syntax for defining React components.

Example of a React component in a .tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';

interface MyComponentProps {
  name: string;
}

function MyComponent({ name }: MyComponentProps) {
  return <div>Hello, {name}!</div>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

In summary, .js files can be used for writing React components in plain JavaScript with JSX, .jsx files are explicitly named with the .jsx extension for JavaScript with JSX, and .tsx files are used for TypeScript with JSX to add static type checking to your React code. The choice between them depends on your project's requirements and your preference for type safety.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

When you need to write JSX but want type safety too, use .tsx, for small projects use .js, and for everything else use .jsx.