# React-native: TS2786: View cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: react-native

I'm new to the react and react-native world. My configuration files are as follows:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "lint": "eslint . **/*.ts *.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14"
  },
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2021", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
    },
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "types": ["react-native"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ],
}
```

I copied the following piece of code in `react-native` into my `App.tsx` file to verify that everything is working correctly:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and I have the following errors:

- TS2607: JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a  props  property.
- TS2786:  Text  cannot be used as a JSX component.
- TS2786:  View  cannot be used as a JSX component.

I have already tried most of the solutions I found around the web, on stackoverflow and on reddit, but none of them solved my problem.

In particular I tried to:

- Added `"resolutions": { "@types/react": "^18.2.0", "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0" },` to my package.json and launched yarn install (after deleting node_modules and yarn.lock)
- I tried to put the same version (`18.2.X`) to `@types/react, @types/react-dom, react, react-dom)`
- Added `"jsx": "react-native"` and `"paths": { "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ] }` to my `tsconfig.json`
- Wrap the component in App with a React fragment (`<React.Fragment> </React.Fragment>`) or a empty tap (`<> </>`)
- I ran `yarn add @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest --dev` and `yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest` (after deleting node_modules and yarn.lock)

I don't know what else I tried, but unfortunately I still didn't find a solution. All of this is quite discouraging for those approaching a new technology for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the bug! The problem is in the `tsconfig.json` because only the files inside `src/` are included in the `"include":[]` property but `App.tsx` must be in the root of the project so it wasn't considered!

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine but it is on jsx(JavaScript XML) you need to code in tsx(TypeScript XML)

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Make sure that your file extension is ".tsx"

Refer to this for more details [What is the difference between .js, .tsx and .jsx in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343698/what-is-the-difference-between-js-tsx-and-jsx-in-react)

Comment: I tried copying your code into my `App.tsx` file, but I get the same errors as before ):

Comment: run "npm install typescript@latest --save-dev" in your project Double-check your tsconfig.json file. 
stop everything which helps to run the project then do "npm install" .

Comment: I ran `yarn add typescript@latest --dev`, rechecked the config file, ran `yarn install`, but I still get those errors. I'm going crazy

Comment: recheck the `tsconfig.json` file I found the error. Thank you